# Oracle 11gR2 loading multiple files: sqlldr or external tables?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, oracle11gr2

I have 471 files totaling about 100GB. The files are "\t" separate, with transaction data in the following format:

```
char(10) not null,
char(8) not null,
char(1) not null,
char(4) not null,
number not null,
char(1) not null,
char(1) not null,
char(1) not null,
number not null
```

The order of the transactions in the files is important and needs to be preserved, ideally with a primary key id. Initially, I loaded these files with sqlldr but it takes a very long time. I recently learned about external tables. From a strategic perspective, which method is better? How does the external table work? Thank you.

Comment: *How does the external table work?* That's fully documented in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/et_concepts.htm

Comment: why would sqlldr take a long time?  Try direct load, and make sure your data is on same local subnet or SAN (or basically, not pushing data through small pipe across the network, like a server in NJ pushing to a db in CA).  Some restrictions for direct load, but MUCH faster.

Comment: I calucated that sqlldr is loading at a rate of 85 million rows per hour. Based on talking with one guy, this seems reasonable, but he is not an expert. There is a commit every 300k rows. An oracle sequence generates a primary key on the insert. The order of the data is important and the key preserves the order. The files are on a drive on the same server as the database. Can a better rate be accomplished?

Answer (score 3):

The record parsing of External Tables and SQL*Loader is very similar, so normally 
there is not a major performance difference in the same record format.  However, 
External Tables may be more appropriate in the following situations:

- You want to transform the data as it is being loaded into the database.
- You want to load data, and additional indexing of the staging table is required.
- You want to use transparent parallel processing without having to split the external data first.

However, in the following situations, use SQL*Loader for the best load performance:

- You want to load data remotely.
- Transformations are not required on the data, and the data does not need to be loaded in parallel.

To improve the performance of SQL*Loader the following suggestions have been made.

- Do not have any indexes and/or constraints (primary keys) on your load 
  tables during the load process
- Add the following option in the command line:  DIRECT=TRUE.  This will 
  bypass most of the RDBMS processing by using the direct path loader 
  instead of the conventional path loader.  However, there are some cases 
  when you can’t use direct load.   These restrictions can be obtained from the 
  Oracle Server Utilities Guide
- Use fixed width data rather than delimited data.  For delimited data, each 
  record needs to be scanned for the delimiter
- Try to avoid character set conversions as conversions are both time and cpu 
  intensive
- For conventional path, use the READSIZE and BINDSIZE parameters.
  READSIZE will grab larger chunks of data per read system call.  The 
  BINDSIZE parameter specifies the size of the bind array, which in turn 
  specifies the number of rows which will be loaded per batch

Source: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/database/enterprise_edition/utilities/pdf/sql_loader_faq.pdf

Comment: This would have been +1 but for "use fix width data". Nobody _asks_ their client for fixed with surely?

Comment: @FlorinGhita You are correct, I am not sure why Oracle would put this in their documentation...

Comment: @ben On rare occasions fixed length data is plausible.

Comment: Fixed width data is very common on non-unix, non-windows platforms.